# Xubuntu 12.10 won't boot into desktop on XPS L502x

Tags: 12.10, kernel, xubuntu, bumblebee

My Xubuntu 12.10 won't boot into desktop on XPS L502x after today's update and reboot (newer version of linux kernel included).

When I installed Xubuntu 12.10 on this XPS L502x, I got the same problem -- the login screen won't show, but I can Ctrl+Alt+F1 to login to the console. Afterwards, I installed bumblebee, which solved the problem.

However, now the problem comes back again. Although I can still login to a console and type `startx` to get a desktop environment, there are some desktop customizations and settings missing in this environment. I tried to start with the former version of Linux kernel but it didn't help.

Anyone else who has ever met this problem?

Additional info:

Every time I start the desktop environment using `startx`, I will get a crash report from the notification area, saying that `xorg` has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver problem for sure - if you can go back to the drivers you were using before installing bumblebee, might help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional info about `xorg` crashing, here is some info about it.

It's called X.Org (you can call it Xorg, or xorg, it has different names) and it is the public, open-source implementation of the X11 X Window System. By that, I mean that it is the implementation of the display server for the X Window System. The Xfce Desktop Environment is somehow based on X.Org to manage windows. As I said above, X.Org is like a window manager. So, if it crashes, your desktop does not start automatically since there is no window manager and you have to do it manually.

Your desktop customizations and settings are not functioning, since the window manager does not start at all and it does not "remember" the last session. Since the update, a new (sure buggy) version of X.Org may have been installed and returned every setting and customization back to default. This is probably due to the fact that a new `X.Org configuration file (Xorg.conf)` being generated and replacing the old one which had your settings.

Also, the window manager is crashing because its files may have been corrupted, or because it's buggy, or because it has problems changing, generating, or saving the X.Org configuration file.

***More info***:

1) [Xorg - ArchWiki (ArchLinux Wiki)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg)

2) [X.Org Foundation (Original Website)](https://www.x.org/wiki/)

3) [X.Org Server - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server)